# Tensor product and conjugate space

Tags: tensor-products

Let $H$ and $K$ be Hilbert spaces and $\overline{K}$ be the conjugate space of $K$, i.e., the elements of $\overline{K}$ are the same of $K$, the sum and norm are the same, and the product rule is given by $\lambda . x$ = $\overline{\lambda}x$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, $x \in K$.

Can we identify the Hilbert spaces $H \otimes \overline{K}$ and $\overline{H \otimes K}$?

What about the spaces $B(H \otimes K)$ and $B(H \otimes \overline{K})$. More specifically, if $a_j \in B(H)$, $b_j \in B(K)$, $1 \leq j \leq n$, is it true that

\begin{equation}
\|\sum a_j \otimes b_j\|_{B(H \otimes K)} = \|\sum a_j \otimes \overline{b_j}\|_{B(H \otimes \overline{K})}
\end{equation}

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, as $ \ \overline{K} \cong K$, you can identify $$H \otimes \overline{K} \cong H \otimes K \cong \overline{H \otimes K}$$ For your second question, what is this notation "$B(H)$"?

Comment: $B(H)$ is the space of bounded linear operators $T: H \rightarrow H$.

Comment: And isn't the identification $\overline{K} \cong K$ conjugate-linear?

Comment: Yes, you are correct